# WP_Query($args) are not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

i am new to wordpress. i pass customized argument to WP_Query Function. Its Return Invalid Result. I limit Products per page 10 but it show all products.

**$args - Print Result**

> Array ( [post_type] => product [posts_per_page] => 10 [post_status] =>
>   publish [paged] => 1 [orderby] => [order] => [meta_query] => Array (
>   [0] => Array ( ) ) [tax_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [taxonomy] =>
>   product_cat [field] => slug [terms] => Array ( [0] =>
>   traditional-pizza ) [operator] => IN ) ) )

**After get Product**

> WP_Query Object ( [query] => Array ( [post_type] => product
>   [posts_per_page] => 20 [post_status] => publish [paged] => 0 [orderby]
>   => [order] => [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) [tax_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [taxonomy] => product_cat [field] => slug [terms] => Array ( [0] => traditional-pizza ) [operator] => IN ) ) )
>   [query_vars] => Array ( [post_type] => product [posts_per_page] => 999
>   [post_status] => publish [paged] => 0 [orderby] => [order] => DESC
>   [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( ) ) [tax_query] => Array ( [0]
>   => Array ( [taxonomy] => product_cat [field] => slug [terms] => Array ( [0] => traditional-pizza ) [operator] => IN ) ) [error] => [m] =>
>   [p] => 0 [post_parent] => [subpost] => [subpost_id] => [attachment] =>
>   [attachment_id] => 0 [name] => [static] => [pagename] => [page_id] =>
>   0 [second] => [minute] => [hour] => [day] => 0 [monthnum] => 0 [year]
>   => 0 [w] => 0 [category_name] => [tag] => [cat] => [tag_id] => [author] => [author_name] => [feed] => [tb] => [meta_key] =>
>   [meta_value] => [preview] => [s] => [sentence] => [title] => [fields]
>   => [menu_order] => [embed] => [category__in] => Array ( ) [category__not_in] => Array ( ) [category__and] => Array ( )
>   [post__in] => Array ( ) [post__not_in] => Array ( ) [post_name__in] =>
>   Array ( ) [tag__in] => Array ( ) [tag__not_in] => Array ( ) [tag__and]
>   => Array ( ) [tag_slug__in] => Array ( ) [tag_slug__and] => Array ( ) [post_parent__in] => Array ( ) [post_parent__not_in] => Array ( )
>   [author__in] => Array ( ) [author__not_in] => Array ( )
>   [ignore_sticky_posts] => [suppress_filters] => [cache_results] => 1
>   [update_post_term_cache] => 1 [lazy_load_term_meta] => 1
>   [update_post_meta_cache] => 1 [nopaging] => [comments_per_page] => 50
>   [no_found_rows] => [taxonomy] => product_cat [term] =>
>   traditional-pizza ) [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object ( [queries] =>
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [taxonomy] => product_cat [terms] => Array (
>   [0] => traditional-pizza ) [field] => slug [operator] => IN
>   [include_children] => 1 ) ) [relation] => AND
>   [table_aliases:protected] => Array ( [0] => wp_term_relationships )
>   [queried_terms] => Array ( [product_cat] => Array ( [terms] => Array (
>   [0] => traditional-pizza ) [field] => slug ) ) [primary_table] =>
>   wp_posts [primary_id_column] => ID ) [meta_query] => WP_Meta_Query
>   Object ( [queries] => Array ( ) [relation] => AND [meta_table] =>
>   [meta_id_column] => [primary_table] => [primary_id_column] =>
>   [table_aliases:protected] => Array ( ) [clauses:protected] => Array (
>   ) [has_or_relation:protected] => ) [date_query] => [request] => SELECT
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN
>   wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID =
>   wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND (
>   wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (48) ) AND
>   wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((wp_posts.post_status =
>   'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
>   LIMIT 0, 999 [posts] => Array ( [0] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] => 922
>   [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:12 [post_date_gmt]
>   => 2019-03-14 20:29:12 [post_content] => [post_title] => Chocolate pizza [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] =>
>   open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] =>
>   chocolate-pizza [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14
>   20:29:18 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:18
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-125/
>   [menu_order] => 25 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [1] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   919 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:10
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:10 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,chicken,pineapple with BBQ sauce. [post_title] => BBQ
>   CHICKEN [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] =>
>   closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] =>
>   bbq-chicken [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-15
>   00:15:31 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-15 00:15:31
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-122/
>   [menu_order] => 22 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [2] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   920 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:10
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:10 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,chicken,pineapple,bacon,prawns. [post_title] => CHICKEN
>   ROYALE [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] =>
>   open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] =>
>   chicken-royale [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14
>   20:29:17 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:17
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-123/
>   [menu_order] => 23 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [3] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   921 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:10
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:10 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,minced beef with onion and oregano. [post_title] => BEEF
>   PIZZA [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] =>
>   open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] =>
>   beef-pizza [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14
>   20:29:18 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:18
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-124/
>   [menu_order] => 24 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [4] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   917 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:09
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:09 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,ham,mushroom,capsicum,hot salami,jalapenos with chilli.
>   [post_title] => VOLCANO [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish
>   [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] =>
>   [post_name] => volcano [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] =>
>   2019-03-14 20:29:17 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:17
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-120/
>   [menu_order] => 20 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [5] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   918 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:09
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:09 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,mushroom,chicken and garlic. [post_title] => CHICKEN
>   [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open
>   [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => chicken
>   [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14 20:29:17
>   [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:17 [post_content_filtered] =>
>   [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-121/
>   [menu_order] => 21 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [6] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   913 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:08
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:08 [post_content] =>
>   HAWAIAN,MARGHERITA,AUSSIE AND MEATLOVERS. [post_title] => FOUR
>   QUARTERS [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status]
>   => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => four-quarters [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14
>   20:29:17 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:17
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-116/
>   [menu_order] => 16 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [7] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   914 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:08
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:08 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,assorted seafood mix with garlic and oregano.
>   [post_title] => MARINARA [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish
>   [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] =>
>   [post_name] => marinara [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] =>
>   2019-03-14 20:29:17 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:17
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-117/
>   [menu_order] => 17 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [8] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   915 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:08
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:08 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,ham,mushroom,onion,capcicum,pineapple,olives,bacon,hotsalami,prawns.
>   [post_title] => THE LOT [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish
>   [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed [post_password] =>
>   [post_name] => the-lot [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] =>
>   2019-03-15 00:16:15 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-15 00:16:15
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-118/
>   [menu_order] => 18 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [9] => WP_Post Object ( [ID] =>
>   916 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:08
>   [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:08 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,ham ,mushroom,onion,capsicum,hot
>   salami,bacon,olives,chilli and oregano. [post_title] => HOUSE SPECIAL
>   [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed
>   [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] =>
>   house-special [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-15
>   00:16:42 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-15 00:16:42
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-119/
>   [menu_order] => 19 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [10] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 909 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:07 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:07 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,olives,anchovies and oregano. [post_title] => NAPOLETANA
>   [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed
>   [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => napoletana
>   [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-25 15:09:19
>   [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-25 15:09:19 [post_content_filtered] =>
>   [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-112/
>   [menu_order] => 12 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [11] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 910 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:07 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:07 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,loads of bacon end egg. [post_title] => EGG AND BACON
>   [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open
>   [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] =>
>   egg-and-bacon [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14
>   20:29:16 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:16
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-113/
>   [menu_order] => 13 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [12] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 911 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:07 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:07 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,ham,mushroom,bacon,prawns and egg. [post_title] => SUPER
>   AUSSIE [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] =>
>   open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] =>
>   super-aussie [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14
>   20:29:16 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:16
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-114/
>   [menu_order] => 14 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [13] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 912 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:07 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:07 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,ham,bacon,chicken,hot salami with BBQ sauce.
>   [post_title] => MEATLOVERS [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish
>   [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] =>
>   [post_name] => meatlovers [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] =>
>   2019-03-14 20:29:17 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:17
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-115/
>   [menu_order] => 15 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [14] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 906 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:06 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:06 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,ham ,capsicum and hot salami. [post_title] => AMERICANA
>   [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed
>   [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => americana
>   [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-15 00:09:46
>   [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-15 00:09:46 [post_content_filtered] =>
>   [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-109/
>   [menu_order] => 9 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [15] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 907 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:06 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:06 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,capsicum,hot salami with chilli. [post_title] =>
>   MEXICANA [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status]
>   => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => mexicana [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14
>   20:29:15 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:15
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-110/
>   [menu_order] => 10 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [16] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 908 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:06 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:06 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,hot salami,olives and anchovies. [post_title] =>
>   PEPPERONI [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status]
>   => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => pepperoni [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14
>   20:29:15 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:15
>   [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-111/
>   [menu_order] => 11 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [17] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 905 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:05 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:05 [post_content] => Tomato,cheese
>   ,egg,ham,bacon and egg. [post_title] => AUSSIE [post_excerpt] =>
>   [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] =>
>   closed [post_password] => [post_name] => aussie [to_ping] => [pinged]
>   => [post_modified] => 2019-03-15 00:13:14 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-15 00:13:14 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0
>   [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-108/
>   [menu_order] => 8 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [18] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 904 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:04 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:04 [post_content] => Tomato,cheese
>   ,ham ,mushrooms,olives and anchovies. [post_title] => CAPPRICIOSA
>   [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open
>   [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => cappriciosa
>   [to_ping] => [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14 20:29:15
>   [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:15 [post_content_filtered] =>
>   [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-107/
>   [menu_order] => 7 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [19] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 903 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:02 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:02 [post_content] => Tomato,cheese
>   ,ham and mushrooms. [post_title] => CAPPRI [post_excerpt] =>
>   [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] =>
>   closed [post_password] => [post_name] => cappri [to_ping] => [pinged]
>   => [post_modified] => 2019-03-14 20:29:15 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:15 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0
>   [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-106/
>   [menu_order] => 6 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [20] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 901 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:01 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:01 [post_content] =>
>   Tomato,cheese,mushroom,onion,capsicum,olives and pineapples.
>   [post_title] => VEGETERIAN(v) [post_excerpt] => [post_status] =>
>   publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] => closed
>   [post_password] => [post_name] => vegeterianv [to_ping] => [pinged] =>
>   [post_modified] => 2019-03-15 00:25:22 [post_modified_gmt] =>
>   2019-03-15 00:25:22 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0
>   [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-104/
>   [menu_order] => 4 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [21] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 902 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:01 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:01 [post_content] => Tomato,cheese
>   ,ham and pineapples. [post_title] => HAWAIAN [post_excerpt] =>
>   [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] =>
>   closed [post_password] => [post_name] => hawaian [to_ping] => [pinged]
>   => [post_modified] => 2019-03-15 00:24:10 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-15 00:24:10 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0
>   [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-105/
>   [menu_order] => 5 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [22] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 897 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:28:59 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:28:59 [post_content] => Tomato,double
>   cheese and oregano. [post_title] => MARGHERITA(V) [post_excerpt] =>
>   [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] =>
>   closed [post_password] => [post_name] => margheritav [to_ping] =>
>   [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-25 12:04:16 [post_modified_gmt]
>   => 2019-03-25 12:04:16 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-100/
>   [menu_order] => 0 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [23] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 898 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:28:59 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:28:59 [post_content] => Garlic,double
>   cheese,oregano and salt. [post_title] => GARLIC(v) [post_excerpt] =>
>   [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] =>
>   closed [post_password] => [post_name] => garlicv [to_ping] => [pinged]
>   => [post_modified] => 2019-03-25 14:55:56 [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-03-25 14:55:56 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0
>   [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-101/
>   [menu_order] => 1 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [24] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 899 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:28:59 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:28:59 [post_content] => garlic,cheese
>   and herbs. [post_title] => FOCACCIA(V) [post_excerpt] => [post_status]
>   => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] => [post_name] => focacciav [to_ping] => [pinged] =>
>   [post_modified] => 2019-03-14 20:29:14 [post_modified_gmt] =>
>   2019-03-14 20:29:14 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0
>   [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-102/
>   [menu_order] => 2 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [25] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 900 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:28:59 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:28:59 [post_content] => Tomato ,loads
>   of mushroom with cheese. [post_title] => MUSHROOM(V) [post_excerpt] =>
>   [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => closed [ping_status] =>
>   closed [post_password] => [post_name] => mushroomv [to_ping] =>
>   [pinged] => [post_modified] => 2019-03-15 00:26:09 [post_modified_gmt]
>   => 2019-03-15 00:26:09 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0 [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-103/
>   [menu_order] => 3 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) ) [post_count] => 26
>   [current_post] => -1 [in_the_loop] => [post] => WP_Post Object ( [ID]
>   => 922 [post_author] => 1 [post_date] => 2019-03-14 20:29:12 [post_date_gmt] => 2019-03-14 20:29:12 [post_content] => [post_title]
>   => Chocolate pizza [post_excerpt] => [post_status] => publish [comment_status] => open [ping_status] => closed [post_password] =>
>   [post_name] => chocolate-pizza [to_ping] => [pinged] =>
>   [post_modified] => 2019-03-14 20:29:18 [post_modified_gmt] =>
>   2019-03-14 20:29:18 [post_content_filtered] => [post_parent] => 0
>   [guid] =>
>   http://localhost/harvestpizza/product/import-placeholder-for-125/
>   [menu_order] => 25 [post_type] => product [post_mime_type] =>
>   [comment_count] => 0 [filter] => raw ) [comment_count] => 0
>   [current_comment] => -1 [found_posts] => 26 [max_num_pages] => 1
>   [max_num_comment_pages] => 0 [is_single] => [is_preview] => [is_page]
>   => [is_archive] => 1 [is_date] => [is_year] => [is_month] => [is_day] => [is_time] => [is_author] => [is_category] => [is_tag] => [is_tax] => 1 [is_search] => [is_feed] => [is_comment_feed] => [is_trackback] => [is_home] => [is_404] => [is_embed] => [is_paged] => [is_admin] => [is_attachment] => [is_singular] => [is_robots] => [is_posts_page] =>
>   [is_post_type_archive] => 1 [query_vars_hash:WP_Query:private] =>
>   5efdffdb75153bccce8880eb2980f959 [query_vars_changed:WP_Query:private]
>   => 1 [thumbnails_cached] => [stopwords:WP_Query:private] => [compat_fields:WP_Query:private] => Array ( [0] => query_vars_hash [1]
>   => query_vars_changed ) [compat_methods:WP_Query:private] => Array ( [0] => init_query_flags [1] => parse_tax_query ) )

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array( 
   'post_type'=>'product', 
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'no_found_rows' => true, 
   'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
   'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
   'nopaging' => true,
  'order' => 'DESC', 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Modify it as per your need. I hope it will work fine :)